# Расположенные в ряд иконки с центрированной снизу надписью

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь сделать адаптивное меню с квадратными иконками и надписью под ними. Изображение я смог уместить в центре блока, но как добавить под каждый пункт надпись я не могу понять. Всё что я придумал, это прописать тегу

абсолютное позиционирование и сместить его вниз, но разместить в центре его не получается

```css
.square {
  width: 76px;
  box-shadow: rgba(46, 45, 36, 0.15) 0px 0px 6px, rgba(46, 45, 36, 0.15) 0px 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 76px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.square img {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.square p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -42px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">

    <div class="square">
      <img src="/assets/icons/homework.svg" alt="">
      <p>My marks</p>
    </div>

    <div class="square">
      <img src="/assets/icons/exams.svg" alt="">
      <p>Exams</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем всё позиционировать абсолютом?

Comment: @De.Minov, потому что других вариантов я не придумал. Но картинка смотрится нормально. Высота и ширина блока .square регулируется медиа запросами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```css
.square {
  width: 76px;
  box-shadow: rgba(46, 45, 36, 0.15) 0px 0px 6px, rgba(46, 45, 36, 0.15) 0px 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 76px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.square img {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.square p {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">

    <div class="square">
      <img src="/assets/icons/homework.svg" alt="">
      <p>My marks</p>
    </div>

    <div class="square">
      <img src="/assets/icons/exams.svg" alt="">
      <p>Exams</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Если требуется объяснение работы кода, пишите, расскажу.

---

[`transform: translateX(-50%)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX) позволяет сдвинуть блок по X относительно своей позиции на половину ширины блока (-50%), что в совокупности с `left: 50%`, визуально разместит блок строго по центру, даже если ширина родителя будет меньше ширины данного блока.

Так же я указал вместо `bottom: -42px` значение `top: calc(100% + 5px)`, что позволит разместить блок `p` на 5px от родителя не зависимо от того, какой размер будет у родителя или у самого `p`.
Т.к. при увеличение размера `p` блок будет верхнем краем оставаться на позиции и "расти вниз", а в случае `bottom: -42px` наоборот, нижней частью на позиции и "расти вверх".

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.test {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px dashed #f00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.test:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.test .p {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00f;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-animation: resize 2s linear infinite;
  animation: resize 2s linear infinite;
}

.i1 .p {
  bottom: -57px;
}

.i2 .p {
  top: calc(100% + 7px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes resize {
  40%,
  60% {
    height: 100px;
  }
  10%,
  90%,
  100% {
    height: 50px;
  }
}

@keyframes resize {
  40%,
  60% {
    height: 100px;
  }
  10%,
  90%,
  100% {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test i1">bottom
  <div class="p"></div>
</div>

<div class="test i2">top
  <div class="p"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Именно! Благодарю. Боюсь тратить ваше время на объяснение, буду разбираться сам.

Comment: Ничего страшного, дополнил ответ небольшой информацией.